# AppDatabase_Impl does not exist Room, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am writing my app in Mobile, Kotlin with using Room. But when I tried open Activity where database must be created I see the next messages:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testtask/com.example.testtask.ui.DetailsScreenActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.testtask.data.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist...at com.example.testtask.ui.DetailsScreenActivity.onCreate(DetailsScreenActivity.kt:86)
```

But if we look there we will see

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            ImageDatabase::class.java,
            "app_database"
        ).build()
```

My database class:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [ImageEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class ImageDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun imageDao(): ImageDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: ImageDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ImageDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(ImageDatabase::class) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ImageDatabase::class.java,
                        "app_database"
                    ).build()
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

My DAO:

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface ImageDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM images")
    suspend fun getAllImages(): List<ImageEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertImage(image: ImageEntity)

}
```

My data class:

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "images")
data class ImageEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val originalUrl: String?,
    val photographer: String?,
    val mediumUrl: String?
)
```

And my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
        classpath "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.testtask'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testtask"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0"

}
```

Please, help me, I really don't understand what's the problem?

I have tried using ksp instead of kapt but I had`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: androidx/room/RoomKspProcessor$Provider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0` error